# Extracting email id gives error

Tags: python, nlp, pandas, nltk

I am extracting email ids and storing them into a new column variable, but I am getting the issue:

[image]

```
    import re
    def email_extract(comments):
        comments1 =re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',comments)
       return comments1

   data["email_id"] = data.COMMENTS.apply(lambda x: email_extract(x))
```

---

> ```
> --- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-33-d9b73bdc4f8e> in <module>()
> ----> 1 data["email_id"] = data.COMMENTS.apply(lambda x: email_extract(x))
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in
> apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    3192            
> else:    3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
> -> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)    
> 3195     3196         if len(mapped) and
> isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
>
> pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
>
> <ipython-input-33-d9b73bdc4f8e> in <lambda>(x)
> ----> 1 data["email_id"] = data.COMMENTS.apply(lambda x: email_extract(x))
>
> <ipython-input-32-97f3705d1972> in email_extract(comments)
>       2 def email_extract(comments):
>       3     #re_pattern = re.compile(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+')
> ----> 4     comments1 =re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',comments)
>       5     return comments1
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda4\lib\re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
>     221 
>     222     Empty matches are included in the result."""
> --> 223     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
>     224 
>     225 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):
>
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
> ```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: seems to be no string... try str(comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have missing data (e.g. `np.nan`s) in your `COMMENTS` field. This will throw an error in your `email_extract` function.
Try to filter the problematic rows out, e.g. with

```
filtered_data = data[~data.COMMENTS.isna()] #purge problematic comments
```

and applying the email extraction to the now "clean" column:

```
filtered_data.COMMENTS.apply(lambda x: email_extract(x))
```

Comment: yes comments had null value.It worked after filtering null. Thanks